# Problem executing SSIS Package on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS project that contains a script task and locally it works perfectly fine on debug, giving the correct results. I deploy to local server and again, it works perfectly fine.

Now when I try to deploy it on a remote server (sending the ispac and executing it from there), it finishes succesfully with no error at all! but when I'm going to execute a job using said SSIS package, it drops the following error.

> Error: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.

I've tried many things found while searching, like rebuilding, editing the script and building again, setting DelayValidation to true...to no avail...What else could I try?

EDIT: @@Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)
    Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Can you add the result from `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: Added the version

Comment: You are running SQL 2014 RTM, which means that you are several Service Packs behind. There is no guarantee that it will help, but still, please first try installing SQL 2014 SP3. For a complete list of versions and Service Packs, see here: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

Comment: You don't mention which SQL Server version is installed on your local SQL Server, I assume it is different than 2014. SSIS packages have a TargetServerVersion property which should match the SQL Server version you are deploying to. Make sure TargetServerVersion is set to 2014 and rebuild the entire script package before deploying it.

Comment: I'm developing on VS2012 SSDT and I don't see the target server version property, how could I set it for 2014?